# Which citation style is used in the following article?

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I'm writing a math paper on TexShop and BibDesk, and I was wondering which citation style is used on this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.07584.pdf). In particular, notice the all-capitalized authors' names. I'm using `\bibliographystyle{amsplain}` and it doesn't like the same.

Also, I can't find a field on BibDesk for place of publication for books. Does anyone know how to add it?

---

I'm not sure if this question is on-topic for this stack, please let me know.

Comment: All arxiv latex made articles must include sources, so I'd just look in the sources. Please don't include more than one question, thus post a new one about BibDesk (people knowing anything about BibDesk would never look at this question)

Comment: The article is not using a style as such, the bibliography is hardcoded, aka formatted by hand.